# Populate dropdown list by previous selection Spring Boot Thymeleaf

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, spring-boot, thymeleaf

I have a table of Customers which I pass to my HTML page. Inside the Customers list there's a list of Orders.  I want to display a dropdown of orders when I select a customer from another dropdown.
I know I cannot achieve that with Thymeleaf and Spring Boot alone, so I will need jQuery or Javascript.
I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53654000/how-to-populate-dropdown-list-by-previous-selection-spring-thymeleaf) solution but it's not working for me aka **NOT DISPLAYING ANY VALUES FOR ORDERS**. I am not sure if it's wrong or right since I don't have experience with jQuery or Javascript.

Could someone tell me how to fix it?

This is the first select:

```
<select id="customer" name="customer" onclick="onCustomerChanged()">
            <option th:each="customer : ${customers}" 
                th:value="${customer.id}" 
                th:text="${customer.name}">
            </option>
</select>
```

And this is the second one:

```
<select id="orders" name="orderId"></select>
```

Then I add this at the end:

```js
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
 <script>
 
 var customers = [[${customers}]];

 function onCustomerChanged() {
  var chosenCustomer = $("customer").val();
  for (i=0;i<customers.length;i++) {
   if (customers[i].id == chosenCustomer) {
    $('#orders option').remove();
    orders = customers[i].orders;
    for (n=0;m<orders.length;n++) {
     $('#orders').append($('<option>', {
      value: orders[n].id,
      text: orders[n].name
     }));
    }
    $("#orders").trigger("chosen:updated");
   }
  }
 }
 </script>
```

I can see that the **var customers** is populated so I believe there is something wrong with the function. Console gives "**Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier**"

This is how the second dropdown looks like (empty)
[image: empty dropdown]

Comment: *"not working"* is a  virtually meaningless problem statement

Comment: It means that it's not showing any values for Orders

Comment: Seem to have extra set of `[]` wrapping `${customers}`. What does the generated source look like?

Comment: var customers = [Customer [id=3, name=Dave, description=test]]; looks like this

Comment: That is not valid javascript syntax. If that's what you really see it will throw error in your browser dev tools console

Comment: yes, it gives Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier

Comment: Need someone familiar with those java frameworks ( which I am not) to pass valid data to the javascript variable. Update the question accordingly